# "main cannot be resolved" when creating a list

Tags: anylogic

I wanted to create a list which can then be called up with a button. The list contains all agents (packages) which which are created by the source.

I can not get rid of the error message.

I checked that the variable packageList is public and I have tried to correct Chatgpt's suggestions for improvement. [image: Anylogic screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you are already in the main agent environment. So you do not need to call main here. Just change the code to :

```
packageList.add(agent);
```

Comment: oh great! Do you also know why I get the error message im my button: "The local variable packageList may not have been initialized".I have to code: java.util.List<Package> packageList = packageList;

for (Package packageAgent : packageList) {
    traceln("Package-Agent: " + packageAgent.getName());
}. I have created a list at variable packageList with Type: Other: List and initial value: new java.util.ArrayList()

Comment: Why did you assign packageList to another list? you can use it directly without any assignment. If you want to copy one list to another, the equal assignment does not copy one list to another but creates a reference to the same list.  for the error you are getting it means that the initial value is not working as expected. try to specify the parameter type of the List in the angle brackets as List<Package> inside the packageList variable and make sure that the List is imported from java.util in the import section. Hope this helps you.